# wxpython disable Context Menu in TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

Hey. I am trying to disable the Context Menu in a TextCtrl widget under wxpython (prevent the context menu from coming up when right clicked). If I create my on Menu and bind it to the right mouse click it will always show my menu but if I dont create menu under right mouse click event it automatically creates a standard conext menu, even if I dont call event.Skip() (see sample code). Is this a bug? Any ideas for a way around this standard context menu?

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnMouseRightDown)

def OnMouseRightDown(self, event):
    pt = event.GetPosition()
    self.RightClickContext(event, pt, True)

def RightClickContext(self, event, pt, enable):

    menu = wx.Menu()
    undo = menu.Append(ID_UNDO, 'Undo')
    menu.AppendSeparator()
    cut = menu.Append(ID_CUT, 'Cut')
    copy = menu.Append( ID_COPY, 'Copy' )        
    paste = menu.Append( ID_PASTE, 'Paste' )
    menu.AppendSeparator()
    delete = menu.Append( ID_DELETE, 'Delete' )
    selectall = menu.Append( ID_SELECTALL, 'Select All' )
    undo.Enable(False)
    cut.Enable(False)
    copy.Enable(False)
    if enable:
        paste.Enable(True)
    else:
        paste.Enable(False)
    delete.Enable(False)
    selectall.Enable(False)

    wx.EVT_MENU(menu, ID_PASTE,  self.MenuPaste)

    self.PopupMenu(menu, pt)
    menu.Destroy()
```

Comment: can you post a fully runnable sample please, as outlined:http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I'm on Python 2.7):

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title='Test', size = (700,500))

        self.screen = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.screen.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.skip)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.screen, 1, wx.GROW | wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def skip(self, evt):
        return

app = wx.App(False)
frame = Test(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Hard to tell without seeing the context of your code, but it could be that you didn't explicitly return, or that there is some other event that is also being processed (like evt_right_up)